# How to control Unity UI Buttons with Keyboard?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, keyboard, mrtk

I have five UI buttons A, B, C, D, and E in a quiz app, for which I want to assign different keys on keyboard, for example, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. `OnClick` method is written in a separate script called QuizUI and it cannot be static. But I keep getting the error message of "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property." What should I write it?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI;

public class Key : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject A;

    private void Update()
    {      
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
        {
            QuizUI.OnClick(A);
        }
    }
}
```

QuizUI code looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI;

public class QuizUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private QuizManager quizManager;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject startButton;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject imageHolder;
    [SerializeField] private Image questionImage;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject questionModel;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject optionHolder;
    [SerializeField] public List<GameObject> options;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject endInfo;

    private Question question;
    private bool answered = false;
    private GameObject clone;
    public Stopwatch stopwatch;

    private void Awake()
    {
        imageHolder.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        optionHolder.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        endInfo.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        var interactable = startButton.GetComponent<Interactable>();
        interactable.OnClick.AddListener(() => Prepare());
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        var interactable = startButton.GetComponent<Interactable>();
        interactable.OnClick.RemoveListener(() => Prepare());
    }

    private void Prepare()
    {
        startButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        imageHolder.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        optionHolder.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        
        //add the listner to all the buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < options.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject localBtn = options[i];
            var interactable = options[i].GetComponent<Interactable>();
            interactable.OnClick.AddListener(() => OnClick(localBtn));
        }
        
        quizManager.StartGame();
    }

    

    public void SetQuestion(Question question)
    {
        //set the question
        this.question = question;
        //check for questionType
        switch (question.questionType)
        {
            case QuestionType.IMAGE:
                questionImage.transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                questionImage.transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);    //activate image holder
                questionModel.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                questionImage.sprite = question.questionImg;           //set the image sprite
                break;

            case QuestionType.MODEL:
                questionImage.transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                questionImage.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                questionModel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                clone = Instantiate(question.questionMdl, new Vector3(0, 0, 0.8f), Quaternion.Euler (0f, -90f, 0f)) as GameObject;
                clone.transform.SetParent(questionModel.transform);
                break;
        }

        //assign options to respective option buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < options.Count; i++)
        {
            options[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = question.options[i];
        }

        answered = false;

        //stopwatch to start
        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
    }

    public void OnClick(GameObject btn)
    {
        if (!answered)
        {
            answered = true;
            bool val = quizManager.Answer(btn.name);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(val);

            DestroyImmediate(clone, true);
            stopwatch.Stop();   //stopwatch to stop
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }
    }

    public void EndGame()
    {
        imageHolder.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        optionHolder.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        endInfo.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I thought about PhysicalPressEventRouter instead of `OnClick` But I'm not clear how it works.

Comment: You need to add a `QuizUI` reference to your `Key` class.  `public QuizUI quizUI;` set it in the inspector, and use that to call your OnClick method.  The message says "you need an object reference because the member you are accessing is not static".

Comment: @hijinxbassist Thank you very much! After adding QuizUI reference, I managed to make it work with `GameObject A = quizUI.options[0];` :)